# Authenticating with

Tags: oauth-2.0, postman, authorization, docusignapi

I am trying to use docusign API, going with the Authorization Code Grant method described in here

https://developers.docusign.com/tools/postman/

I am fairly confident I have followed directions correctly

I have generated a Basic Authorization token with

btoa('integration-key-from-app-settings','secret-from-app-settings')
yielding:
"MGVmZTli....OThmZGYz"

[image: Headers]

Then I entered the following into my browser:

https://account-d.docusign.com/oauth/auth?response_type=code&scope=signature&client_id=0efe9bb8-c2c1-4dd9-b0bc-20f7db98fdf3&redirect_uri=http://localhost.com:9824/ds/callback

It behaves differently sometimes, but it usually just hangs as follows (even though I set up that call back in my app page):

[image: code request]

I copy the code into my postman body:

[image]

When I run my postman Authorize Code Grant Token request, I get the response:

```
    {
    "error": "invalid_grant",
    "error_description": "unauthorized_client"
    }
```

I tried this again with a callback of https://example.com, which gave me a 200, when I copied in the code again, I got that unauthorized client message again

[image: example.com callback]

Comment: Where did you see in the DocuSign documentation that you need to use "Basic" authentication ?

Comment: Step 2 of the documentation you linked, which is different but consistent with the documentation I link in OP and also with the Postman collection I am using     curl --header "Authorization: Basic BASE64_COMBINATION_OF_INTEGRATION_AND_SECRET_KEYS"

Answer (score 0):

The first step is to log in to DocuSign with your clientId and get a code, the `{{codeFromUrl}}` has to be replaced in postman to the code you got when you log into docuSign developer account (in account-d)

Then you need to use OAuth 2.0 and that means you need to generate an access token and then you the header is:

```
Authorization Bearer {access_token}}
```

See more information in the [Auth Code Grant documentation](https://developers.docusign.com/platform/auth/authcode/authcode-get-token/)

Comment: The documentation you link has the same auth endpoint as  the postman collection I am using   .../oauth/token with the same variables in the body and header. The Bearer Token is supposed to be returned by the .../oauth/token but that is what is not working for me

Comment: ok, so to use Auth Code Grant, you need two steps

Comment: The first step, you just use the browser to log in and generate an access code. Does this step work for you?

Comment: Do you have this code in postman? where it says {{codeFromUrl}} ? can you maybe replace this with the code?

Comment: I do replace with code, for about 2 minutes I get 'unauthorized client' but then the code expires and I get 'expired code' error. I am thinking there is something wrong with my callback or with my scope? I am not specifying a scope, and I used example.com for callback

Comment: you need to specify scope, it should be signature

Comment: You should also see a consent screen before you are redirected to example.com, if you never saw that - something is wrong